# Converting image loop to loop with categories and images within

Tags: json, backbone.js

I started a project with a freelancer who was doing the BacboneJS for the front end of a site for me but they never completed. I now need to finish it off with no backbone experience. They had setup the follow code for my image gallery page to loop though all the images and display on the screen, this works however I need it to loop though the categories and then images within so they are grouped together with the category header at the top.

My current code is as follows:

```
render_gallery: function(){
     var $main=this.$el.find('.content-wrap');
     $main.html("");
     var $ul=$main.find("ul");
      _.each(this.collection.models, function(image){
        var image_link='<a class="fancybox" href="'+image.get('path')+'">'+
          '<img alt="" src="'+image.get('thumb_path')+'">'+
         '</a>';
         $main.append(image_link);
      });
      $('.fancybox').fancybox();
    }
```

This runs from the JSON data (snippet only):

```
[{"id":"5","gallery_cat_id":"2","name":"rfg","path":"\/cms\/app\/webroot\/files\/images\/img2.jpg","thumb_path":"\/cms\/app\/webroot\/files\/images\/thumbs\/img2.jpg","size":"149944","sort_order":"10","online":true,"created":"2013-08-16 10:24:37","modified":"2013-08-17 08:37:05"},{"id":"7","gallery_cat_id":"1","name":"","path":"\/cms\/app\/webroot\/files\/images\/p1060956.jpg","thumb_path":"\/cms\/app\/webroot\/files\/images\/thumbs\/p1060956.jpg","size":"404269","sort_order":"1","online":true,"created":"2013-08-22 15:30:40","modified":"2013-08-22 15:30:40"},{"id":"8","gallery_cat_id":"1","name":"","path":"\/cms\/app\/webroot\/files\/images\/p1060959.jpg","thumb_path":"\/cms\/app\/webroot\/files\/images\/thumbs\/p1060959.jpg","size":"258454","sort_order":"2","online":true,"created":"2013-08-22 15:30:57","modified":"2013-08-22 15:30:57"},
```

However I now have this JSON data (snippet only):

```
[{"Restorations":[{"id":"7","gallery_cat_id":"1","name":"","path":"\/cms\/app\/webroot\/files\/images\/p1060956.jpg","thumb_path":"\/cms\/app\/webroot\/files\/images\/thumbs\/p1060956.jpg","size":"404269","sort_order":"1","online":true,"created":"2013-08-22 15:30:40","modified":"2013-08-22 15:30:40"},{"id":"8","gallery_cat_id":"1","name":"","path":"\/cms\/app\/webroot\/files\/images\/p1060959.jpg","thumb_path":"\/cms\/app\/webroot\/files\/images\/thumbs\/p1060959.jpg","size":"258454","sort_order":"2","online":true,"created":"2013-08-22 15:30:57","modified":"2013-08-22 15:30:57"},{"id":"9","gallery_cat_id":"1","name":"","path":"\/cms\/app\/webroot\/files\/images\/p1060964.jpg","thumb_path":"\/cms\/app\/webroot\/files\/images\/thumbs\/p1060964.jpg","size":"309197","sort_order":"3","online":true,"created":"2013-08-22 15:31:10","modified":"2013-08-22 15:31:10"},{"id":"10","gallery_cat_id":"1","name":"","path":"\/cms\/app\/webroot\/files\/images\/p1060972.jpg","thumb_path":"\/cms\/app\/webroot\/files\/images\/thumbs\/p1060972.jpg","size":"195725","sort_order":"4","online":true,"created":"2013-08-22 15:31:49","modified":"2013-08-22 15:32:40"},{"id":"11","gallery_cat_id":"1","name":"","path":"\/cms\/app\/webroot\/files\/images\/p1070598.jpg","thumb_path":"\/cms\/app\/webroot\/files\/images\/thumbs\/p1070598.jpg","size":"229989","sort_order":"5","online":true,"created":"2013-08-22 15:32:02","modified":"2013-08-22 15:32:02"},{"id":"12","gallery_cat_id":"1","name":"","path":"\/cms\/app\/webroot\/files\/images\/p10705991.jpg","thumb_path":"\/cms\/app\/webroot\/files\/images\/thumbs\/p10705991.jpg","size":"250559","sort_order":"6","online":true,"created":"2013-08-22 15:32:14","modified":"2013-08-22 15:32:14"},{"id":"13","gallery_cat_id":"1","name":"","path":"\/cms\/app\/webroot\/files\/images\/pic_3.jpg","thumb_path":"\/cms\/app\/webroot\/files\/images\/thumbs\/pic_3.jpg","size":"191162","sort_order":"7","online":true,"created":"2013-08-22 15:32:27","modified":"2013-08-22 15:32:27"}],"Second Category - Sample":[{"id":"5","gallery_cat_id":"2","name":"rfg","path":"\/cms\/app\/webroot\/files\/images\/img2.jpg","thumb_path":"\/cms\/app\/webroot\/files\/images\/thumbs\/img2.jpg","size":"149944","sort_order":"10","online":true,"created":"2013-08-16 10:24:37","modified":"2013-08-17 08:37:05"},{"id":"14","gallery_cat_id":"2","name":"","path":"\/cms\/app\/webroot\/files\/images\/tlbday3.jpg","thumb_path":"\/cms\/app\/webroot\/files\/images\/thumbs\/tlbday3.jpg","size":"25207","sort_order":"2","online":true,"created":"2013-08-23 14:20:04","modified":"2013-08-23 14:20:04"},{"id":"16","gallery_cat_id":"2","name":"","path":"\/cms\/app\/webroot\/files\/images\/partyhats.jpg","thumb_path":"\/cms\/app\/webroot\/files\/images\/thumbs\/partyhats.jpg","size":"12955","sort_order":"0","online":true,"created":"2013-08-23 14:20:44","modified":"2013-08-23 14:20:44"},{"id":"18","gallery_cat_id":"2","name":"","path":"\/cms\/app\/webroot\/files\/images\/hrc_syd_a5_happyhour_low.jpg","thumb_path":"\/cms\/app\/webroot\/files\/images\/thumbs\/hrc_syd_a5_happyhour_low.jpg","size":"205515","sort_order":"0","online":true,"created":"2013-08-23 14:21:55","modified":"2013-08-27 17:16:28"}]}]
```

With restorations being the first category returned with the images within this.

I'm guessing I need to somehow add in an initial loop before the _each is performed but I cannot work out where to begin or how to go about this. Can someone point me in the right direction?

MY GALLERY MODEL CODE

```
$(function() {
window.app = window.app || { };

    window.app.Gallery = Backbone.Model.extend({
        urlRoot: 'cms/gallery_cats',
        defaults: {
            id: "",
            description: ""
        },
        initialize: function(){
          this.on('change',function(model){
            // alert(this.get('description'));
          });
        },
        parse : function(resp) {
           return resp;
        }
    });

    window.app.GalleryCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
       url: 'cms/gallery_cats',
       model: app.Gallery
    });
});
```

GALLERY VIEW CODE

```
$(function() {
window.app = window.app || { };

    window.app.Gallery = Backbone.Model.extend({
        urlRoot: 'cms/gallery_cats',
        defaults: {
            id: "",
            description: ""
        },
        initialize: function(){
          this.on('change',function(model){
            // alert(this.get('description'));
          });
        },
        parse : function(resp) {
           return resp;
        }
    });

    window.app.GalleryCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
       url: 'cms/gallery_cats',
       model: app.Gallery
    });
});
```

Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up getting this to work as follows:

```
_.each(this.collection.models, function(group){
        _.each(group.attributes,function(image_category,index){
            console.log(image_category);
            //Following code is quick fix for getting categiry name, but will be replaced later.
            $main.append('<h4 style="float: left; margin-bottom: 15px;">'+index+'</h4><br clear="left">');
             _.each(image_category,function(image){
              var link='<a href="'+image.path+'" class="fancybox" rel="'+index+'"><img class="gallery_thumb" src="'+image.thumb_path+'"/></a>';
              $main.append(link);
             });
             $main.append('<br/>');
        });
      });
```

Note the index added to the image_categroy loop.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want to add an extra _each, and slightly change your existing one.  Apologies if this code isn't 100%, as it might need tweaking to suit your data;

```
  // Loop through your data, as each category
  _.each(this.collection.models, function(category){


        // Loop through each image within the category 
        _.each(category, function(image){

              // Output your image
              var image_link='<a class="fancybox" href="'+image.get('path')+'">'+
                    '<img alt="" src="'+image.get('thumb_path')+'">'+
                    '</a>';
              $main.append(image_link);

        });

  });
```

To explain a bit better, you want to change from looping through just images;

```
[
    {
        "id": "5",
        "gallery_cat_id": "2",
        "name": "rfg",
        "path": "/cms/app/webroot/files/images/img2.jpg",
        "thumb_path": "/cms/app/webroot/files/images/thumbs/img2.jpg",
        "size": "149944",
        "sort_order": "10",
        "online": true,
        "created": "2013-08-16 10:24:37",
        "modified": "2013-08-17 08:37:05"
    },
    {
        "id": "7",
        "gallery_cat_id": "1",
        "name": "",
        "path": "/cms/app/webroot/files/images/p1060956.jpg",
        "thumb_path": "/cms/app/webroot/files/images/thumbs/p1060956.jpg",
        "size": "404269",
        "sort_order": "1",
        "online": true,
        "created": "2013-08-22 15:30:40",
        "modified": "2013-08-22 15:30:40"
    },
    {
        "id": "8",
        "gallery_cat_id": "1",
        "name": "",
        "path": "/cms/app/webroot/files/images/p1060959.jpg",
        "thumb_path": "/cms/app/webroot/files/images/thumbs/p1060959.jpg",
        "size": "258454",
        "sort_order": "2",
        "online": true,
        "created": "2013-08-22 15:30:57",
        "modified": "2013-08-22 15:30:57"
    }
]
```

...to looping through each category, and then each image inside that category;

```
[
    {
        "Restorations": [
            {
                "id": "7",
                "gallery_cat_id": "1",
                "name": "",
                "path": "/cms/app/webroot/files/images/p1060956.jpg",
                "thumb_path": "/cms/app/webroot/files/images/thumbs/p1060956.jpg",
                "size": "404269",
                "sort_order": "1",
                "online": true,
                "created": "2013-08-22 15:30:40",
                "modified": "2013-08-22 15:30:40"
            },
            {
                "id": "8",
                "gallery_cat_id": "1",
                "name": "",
                "path": "/cms/app/webroot/files/images/p1060959.jpg",
                "thumb_path": "/cms/app/webroot/files/images/thumbs/p1060959.jpg",
                "size": "258454",
                "sort_order": "2",
                "online": true,
                "created": "2013-08-22 15:30:57",
                "modified": "2013-08-22 15:30:57"
            },
            {
                "id": "9",
                "gallery_cat_id": "1",
                "name": "",
                "path": "/cms/app/webroot/files/images/p1060964.jpg",
                "thumb_path": "/cms/app/webroot/files/images/thumbs/p1060964.jpg",
                "size": "309197",
                "sort_order": "3",
                "online": true,
                "created": "2013-08-22 15:31:10",
                "modified": "2013-08-22 15:31:10"
            },
            {
                "id": "10",
                "gallery_cat_id": "1",
                "name": "",
                "path": "/cms/app/webroot/files/images/p1060972.jpg",
                "thumb_path": "/cms/app/webroot/files/images/thumbs/p1060972.jpg",
                "size": "195725",
                "sort_order": "4",
                "online": true,
                "created": "2013-08-22 15:31:49",
                "modified": "2013-08-22 15:32:40"
            },
            {
                "id": "11",
                "gallery_cat_id": "1",
                "name": "",
                "path": "/cms/app/webroot/files/images/p1070598.jpg",
                "thumb_path": "/cms/app/webroot/files/images/thumbs/p1070598.jpg",
                "size": "229989",
                "sort_order": "5",
                "online": true,
                "created": "2013-08-22 15:32:02",
                "modified": "2013-08-22 15:32:02"
            },
            {
                "id": "12",
                "gallery_cat_id": "1",
                "name": "",
                "path": "/cms/app/webroot/files/images/p10705991.jpg",
                "thumb_path": "/cms/app/webroot/files/images/thumbs/p10705991.jpg",
                "size": "250559",
                "sort_order": "6",
                "online": true,
                "created": "2013-08-22 15:32:14",
                "modified": "2013-08-22 15:32:14"
            },
            {
                "id": "13",
                "gallery_cat_id": "1",
                "name": "",
                "path": "/cms/app/webroot/files/images/pic_3.jpg",
                "thumb_path": "/cms/app/webroot/files/images/thumbs/pic_3.jpg",
                "size": "191162",
                "sort_order": "7",
                "online": true,
                "created": "2013-08-22 15:32:27",
                "modified": "2013-08-22 15:32:27"
            }
        ],
        "Second Category - Sample": [
            {
                "id": "5",
                "gallery_cat_id": "2",
                "name": "rfg",
                "path": "/cms/app/webroot/files/images/img2.jpg",
                "thumb_path": "/cms/app/webroot/files/images/thumbs/img2.jpg",
                "size": "149944",
                "sort_order": "10",
                "online": true,
                "created": "2013-08-16 10:24:37",
                "modified": "2013-08-17 08:37:05"
            },
            {
                "id": "14",
                "gallery_cat_id": "2",
                "name": "",
                "path": "/cms/app/webroot/files/images/tlbday3.jpg",
                "thumb_path": "/cms/app/webroot/files/images/thumbs/tlbday3.jpg",
                "size": "25207",
                "sort_order": "2",
                "online": true,
                "created": "2013-08-23 14:20:04",
                "modified": "2013-08-23 14:20:04"
            },
            {
                "id": "16",
                "gallery_cat_id": "2",
                "name": "",
                "path": "/cms/app/webroot/files/images/partyhats.jpg",
                "thumb_path": "/cms/app/webroot/files/images/thumbs/partyhats.jpg",
                "size": "12955",
                "sort_order": "0",
                "online": true,
                "created": "2013-08-23 14:20:44",
                "modified": "2013-08-23 14:20:44"
            },
            {
                "id": "18",
                "gallery_cat_id": "2",
                "name": "",
                "path": "/cms/app/webroot/files/images/hrc_syd_a5_happyhour_low.jpg",
                "thumb_path": "/cms/app/webroot/files/images/thumbs/hrc_syd_a5_happyhour_low.jpg",
                "size": "205515",
                "sort_order": "0",
                "online": true,
                "created": "2013-08-23 14:21:55",
                "modified": "2013-08-27 17:16:28"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but I ended up with a blank page, nothing shows on the screen now. What other code would you need to see other then what is above? Basically everything is already there from the view and model. Thanks

Comment: Updated to add the full view and model code as I currently had it.

Comment: You might need to update my code to match your data format (ie, 'this.collection.models' in the first each, and 'category' in the second).  I've updated the answer with an explanation.

Comment: Try a console.log(category) and see what it outputs

Comment: Tganks, I get an object for the console.log category but when I console.log image I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Object c9 has no method 'get'

Comment: Could you post your console log from your first 'image' output, and then from my code as well?

Comment: OK I tried that and got this: r {cid: "c9", attributes: Object, collection: r, _changing: false, _previousAttributes: Object…}
_changing: false
_events: Object
_pending: false
_previousAttributes: Object
attributes: Object
changed: Object
cid: "c9"
collection: r
id: ""
__proto__: s

Comment: Thanks for your help with this, I gave you the bounty points for your help. The actual answer is below, just a slight tweak.

Answer (score 0):

No Need of correcting _.each loop..you have to actually update a line where collection of this view is being set from JSON..

you may be creating a collection object some where using this old json...it may be something like this

```
var imageCollection = new ImageCollection(JSON);
```

with new JSON structure it should be like this

```
var imageCollection = new ImageCollection(JSON.Restorations);
```

PS: Let me know your concerns...I will keep on updating the answer until you feel it worked..

Comment: Thanks. Wouldn't that be fixing the gallery received? Restorations is only the first, there are many below that one in the same json. Thanks